# Connecting angular front end to API using kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes

in my env file for my angular frontend I have the API endpoint set as localhost:8000 because my API listens on that port, but it is in a separate pod is this correct or am I meant to use the name I gave to the backend service in the deployment file. Second, how do I connect the backend service is how I have it done in the deployment file below correct?

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ai-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ai-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ai-api
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: ai-api
        image: test.azurecr.io/api:v5
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: ai-api
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ai-api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
  selector:
    app: ai-api
---
# Frontend
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ai-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ai-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ai-front
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: ai-front
        image: test.azurecr.io/front-end:v5.1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: api
          value: "ai-api"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ai-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  #Tells loadbalancer which deployment to use
  selector:
    app: ai-front
```

Comment: As per the yamls , your fronted can reach backend using URL `ai-api:8000`.

Comment: I have tried that but that also doesn't work which is making me think that the service isant connected properly

Comment: Can you reach the API via Pod IP and port combination ?

Comment: Do you mean by loging into the frontend pod and pinging the IP

Comment: Start a test Pod using `kubectl run api_test --image=tutum/curl --restart=Never --rm -it -- /bin/sh` then do `curl <pod_ip>:8000` . Make sure your API listens on "0.0.0.0:8000" (Eg- In NodeJS `.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0");`)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have API endpoint set as `localhost:8000` for your frontend which is not correct as *localhost* is referring to the same pod from which the request is send from (so it means "connect to myself"). Change it to `ai-api:8000`. And also make sure that your api server is listening on `0.0.0.0:8000` and not on `localhost:8000`.

I also see that you are passing the name of your backend service to the frontend pod:

```
env:
- name: api
  value: "ai-api"
```

and if you are using this env to connect to your backend app it would stand in contradiction with your earlier statement that you are connecting to *localhost:8000*.

Comment: I have tried using ai-api:8000 and am getting the error failed to resole also how can I make sure its listening on 0.0.0.0:8000 do I have to set that in my code?

Comment: yes, you have to make sure the app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: You can try to exec to your container and use *netstat* or *ss* if available to check you open ports. e.g you can try `netstat -lnpt`. Speaking of *error failed to resolve*, are these pods/services in the same namespace?

Comment: So I ran the curl cmd and when I ran it the connection timed out for port 8000 and the connection got refused for port 80 the API I am trying to use is the python hug API and im not too sure how to change the binding addess of it

Comment: I think the networking for my pods isant setup correctly I thought it was managed by azure since its an AKS cluster

Comment: networking might be an issue, to check this you can try running your app on minikube or any other cluster.

Comment: I can run my app in minikube works fine with ai-api I have made sure that both the pods are in the same name space

Comment: Update the pods can now communicate with each other so when I do a curl cmd from the frontend pod to ai-api:8000 it works but when I try it from my frontend in the browser I am getting err name not resolved still

Comment: are you trying to connect directly from your browser to *ai-api* ?? or maybe proxing it through frontend?